# AliasMatch and regex?

Tags: regex, apache

I want to do an AliasMatch in apache for my vhost. I want to make this kind of path:

> /folder1/folder2/folder3

to point to

> /folder1/folder2/somethingelse/folder3

but a path can also be just like:

> /folder1/folder2

which then should point to:

> /folder2/folder2/somethingelse

all subfolders have unknown names, its just the folder "somethingelse" i know the name of.

Any sugesstions for a pattern? I got this so far;

`[^/]*((/[^/]*)?)?(.*)`

Comment: What is the difference between `/folder1/folder2/folder3` and `/folder1/folder2` ?

Comment: It was more of a explonation how I wanted the AliasMatch to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+) "/$1/$2/somethingelse"
AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) "/$1/$2/somethingelse/$3"
```